# Calculator for lines that ignore words

Tags: javascript, python

I have like 1000 lines containing something like this:

```
Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each
```

etc.

I need to record the order history and give the final price. I want to have something that calculate each line. Multiply and give me the answers:

```
2000
600
800
200
```

I already removed the $ signs, etc with regex in notepad++. If I remove everything except the digits using regex it will show up as one line.

Doesn't have to be in javascript or python, if there's a trick or a website for me to do it it would be great. I actually have no idea how to do this in javascript or python since I'm new to both javascript and python but for python, I think you can do something with for loops and the strip function. If it's on python I can only drag the file to command prompt.

Comment: can you provide your javascript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<textarea id="mytext" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each
</textarea>

<textarea id="myresult" style="width:400px;height:100px;">
</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var element1 = document.getElementById("mytext");
var element2 = document.getElementById("myresult");
var lines = element1.value.split('\n');
element2.value = '';
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
   var line = lines[i];
   var numbers = line.match(/[0-9]+/g);
   if (numbers.length == 2) {
    element2.value = element2.value + (numbers[0]*numbers[1]);
   }
   element2.value = element2.value + '\n';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdk8e5y3/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall` and `np.prod` to get desired result.

1. `re.findall` returns a list of all the pattern matches. `\d+` is used for number.
2. `np.prod` returns the product of all the elements in it.

---

Python Code:

```
import re
import numpy as np
_str='''Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each'''

for i in _str.split('\n'):
     print(np.prod([int(j) for j in re.findall('\d+',i)]))
```

---

```
2000
600
800
200
```

Comment: I guess you mean `matchAll` on the String.prototype but mind that this is a rather new method that comes with ES2020: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility

Comment: It tells me np is not defined. Remember I can only drag the file to command prompt because I'm new

Comment: @QuotingEddie I wrote the above in python. I used `re` package. ref link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: @IvanMorales Check the edited answer. I forgot to add the import statements

Answer (score 1):

Are there always only two values per row? Try this in JavaScript:

```
const yourString = `Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each`;

const numbers = yourString.match(/\d+/g);

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {
  console.log(numbers[i] * numbers[i + 1]);
}
```

Mind that this is ES2015 ("ES6") standards code, i.e. it won't work as-is in IE11. If you want to run it in older browsers (down to IE4), simply replace the backticks with `"` and put the input string in one line, divided by `\n`. Also replace both `const` and `let` with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

**JS one-liner**

```js
const str = `
Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each
`;

str.trim()
   .split('\n')
   .map(line => 
       line.match(/\d+/g)
       .map(Number)
       .reduce((acc, val) => acc *= val, 1)
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `matchAll`, with a **m**ultiline regex, the 2 numbers can be captured.

Then from those captured groups, the products can be mapped to an array.

Example snippet:

```js
let text = `Brought 20 shoes for 100 each
Brought 3 computers for 200 each
Brought 100 shares of Apple for 8 each
Brought 100 Rubix cube for 2 each`;

let re = /^Brought\s*(\d+).*for\s*(\d+)/mgi;
let broughtTotals = [...text.matchAll(re)].map((x,i)=>parseInt(x[1])*parseInt(x[2]));

broughtTotals.forEach((total, idx)=> document.write(`${total}<br/>`));
```